# Open resource directly in detached editor window

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

In Eclipse 4.x, we finally have the ability to detach editor tabs into floating windows. Is there any way to open files (e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) directly in a new tab in a floating editor window, rather than having to open them in the main window and manually drag them over to the floating window? This is a basic feature I really miss from IntelliJ-based IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more of getting the work flow correct. Do you mean that we should open a *new* detached window for every new editor being opened this way ? Do you mean we should determine whether there's a DW showing editors and use it ?

I think the first one is just going to end up with a *lot* of DW's...

We're already looking at allowing someone (i.e. you) to add a 'policy' hook you could use to determine the appropriate place for newly appearing elements to be shown but I'm not sure when we'll get to it.

Right now there is a built-in policy that does attempt to open a new editor in the same stack as the last active editor, perhaps all we need to do is to extend this behavior to include the case where the last active editor was in a DW.

Comment: This is not quite how StackOverflow answers should be used, but oh well. When I press Ctrl+Shift+R (or any other shortcut that opens a file in an editor), I would expect Eclipse to open the file in the _currently focused_ window -- whether that's the main one or a detached one.